# how to extract date from a string using regex

Tags: c#, regex

i m looking for regex which can extract the date from the following html

```
<p>British Medical Journal, 29.9.12, pp.37-41.</p>
```

and convert it in the format 29/09/12

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Match this pattern: -

```
(\d+)[.](\d+)[.](\d+)
```

and replace with: -

```
$1/$2/$3
```

`\d` is used to match `digits`. Using it with quantifier `(+)`, you would match one or more digits. 
Now, in regex, a `dot(.)` is a metacharacter, that matches any character. To match a `period` literally, you would need to either escape it, or use it inside a character class.

---

To convert to a specific `Date Format`, e.g.: - convert `9` -> `09`, you can make use of a `MatchEvaluator`: -

```
string input = "British Medical Journal, 29.9.12, pp.37-41.";
Regex reg = new Regex(@"(\d+)[.](\d+)[.](\d+)");
string result = reg.Replace(input, delegate(Match m) {
    return m => DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy")
});
```

You can check whether it works or not.

Comment: Doesn't change `9` -> `09`

Answer (score 2):

Here is the regex pattern: `\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}`.

And here is the example of how to parse this string to DateTime:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("29.9.12", "d.M.yy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

`(\d{4})[-](\d{2})[-](\d{2})` use this regex to pick 2017-01-23 format date